# In C++, why does casting to reference of derived type work?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, reference, derived-instances

Precisely, why does `B b = (B&) a` compile and work whereas `B b = (B) a` does not in the below program?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {public: void f(){ cout<<"A"<<endl;} };

class B : public A { public: void f(){cout<<"B"<<endl;} };

void g(A a){  B b = (B&) a; b.f(); }

int main() {
    B b; g(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something about casting to a derived type with reference that I am missing here ? If I just cast to B, it gives a compile time error that the constructor B(A a) does not exist.

Comment: What do you meam by "why"? Do you need a quote from the standard that specifies this behaviour? Or a deep philosophical reason why it would be a bad idea to allow this?

Comment: Obviously the first one. I do not know why the standard allows converting to a derived type reference but not the derived type instance. It would make sense if references are by standard interpreted to be pointers.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` when all you need is `'\n'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the implicit conversion from `A` to `B` doesn't exist, and you didn't define an explicit one either.

Reference casting, on the other hand, is valid because it is allowed for inherited types. More precisely, you can cast both ways between different classes in the same inheritance hierarchy. Same goes for pointers. The related concept is called *polymorphism*, if you'd like some pointers for further study.

Do note, however, that it only makes sense for an object that **is** of type `B`to be cast to `B`. E. g.:

```
B b;
A& aRef = B; // equivalent of A& ref = (A&)B;
B& bRef = (B&)aRef;
```

What you did will fail at runtime as soon as you try to access some data or method of `B` that does not exist in `A`. Because your actual object is `A`, not `B`.

Upcasting (from an descendant to an ascendant) is always safe because any object of a class that inherits the base class **is** a valid base object. The downcasting, however, is dangerous for the exact reason I explained above, and should never be done using a C-style cast. Instead, use `dynamic_cast`:

```
B b;
A& aRef = B;
B& bRef = dynamic_cast<B&>(aRef);
```

`dynamic_cast` uses RTTI (run-time type information) to validate the operation and will throw an `std::bad_cast` exception if the conversion is not valid. This is unlike `dynamic_cast`ing pointers, in which case the cast returns `nullptr` instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: I have ensured it in my function calls that only an instance of derived type is being passed to the function taking the base type as argument. So runtime failure will never occur. 

Also, are you trying to say that type casting to reference of derived type works because behind the scene, C++ interprets references as pointers? Because I know for a fact that using pointers here in place of references would have worked. I was just not sure that this is a C++ standard spec to interpret references as pointers.

Comment: "only an instance of derived type is being passed to the function taking the base type as argument". So why does it take the base type as argument, if it always gets the derived type? What's the point of hiding types from the compiler?

Comment: The standard doesn't *say* that behind the scenes references are pointers - but that is how every compiler implements them

Comment: @Raymond232: references are very similar to pointers, but are a little bit safer (for one, because a reference cannot be uninitialized, unlike pointer).

Comment: @Raymond232 Beside the question which asked by @n.m. your `g` function take an `A` as its parameter, which make an object slicing here, hence, no matter which type you passed to function call, when it go to this function, it will be copy to an `A` object, hence, this code's behavior will be always undefined.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe It isn't `will fail at runtime`, it might fail at runtime since this is an undefined behavior, according to section 5.2.9 [expr.static.cast] in C++ standard

Comment: @Danh: that was poor choice of words on my part. By "fail" I mean it won't work as expected from an object of type `B`. I don't necessarily mean segmentation fault or such.

Comment: This design is not under my control, as it is part of a much bigger design that is being used in my company. To be specific, g(A a) is an interface which is called with instances of various subclasses of A. Then in g's body, depending on what is the type id of the object a, some code is executed. And my company uses g++, while for this code snippet I used Visual studio. Both of them worked fine. In fact, this interface is called millions of times everyday, and never breaks, so I think run time safety is there.

Answer (score 2):

`B b = (B) a` won't work because no conversion (constructor or conversion operator) was defined.
`B b = (B&) a` works because it cast `a` to a reference to B (downcast by a `static_cast`), then call copy constructor of B. However in this case, `a` is not an actual object of `B` so this is undefined behavior.
See [expr.static.cast] in C++ standard

> If the object of type “cv1 B” is actually a subobject of an object of type D, the result refers to the enclosing
>   object of type D. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

and [expr.cast] in C++ standard or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: This wording is confusing; the C-style cast is performing a `reinterpret_cast`, as it allows any lvalue to be cast into a reference of *any type*. It sounds like you're implying that the C-style cast is performing a `static_cast`.

Comment: In [expr.cast] section, and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast, the C-style cast will perform in this order `const_cast`, `static_cast`, `static_cast` (with extensions) followed by `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`

Comment: @CollinDauphinee In this case, it should be performing a `static_cast<B&>`.

Answer (score -1):

Class A has private/public members.
Class B is derived from Class A and may have added more private/public members.

Class B "is a" derivative of Class A. However Class A "is not a" derivative of Class B. (IE: You can downcast A->B but not upcast B-A.)

The reason is that while B is a kind of A, A is not a kind of B so B's methods/members will not be present (even if a method has the same name in the source code it will not be the same method compiled due to name being obscured by the compiler).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: Agreed.  Also, although *I* understand what you are trying to say, nobody who asks the question will.